# Override absolute position on child container (modal window)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a modal window that is pulled from the server and inserted into a container that is absolute positioned. When that window is triggered to open, it does not display properly, it positions itself inside the container and most of it is hidden.

Is there a specific css to be written for the container of the modal window (**MyModalWindow**). My code is as follows:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   <div style="position: absolute;">
     <div id="MyModalWindow"> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is a jquery tools window and attaches the following style to **MyModalWindow** when it shows.:

```
element.style  {
   display:block;
   left:183.5px
   position:absolute;
   top:468.4px;
   z-index:9999;
}
```

I basically need the div to not be a child of the parent, since as jquery calculates it to be positioned at the center of the webpage no matter where the div is.

Comment: Aside from position, what styles do you have set on the two container divs? Can you post the JavaScript you are using to show the modal window?

Comment: Do you have a page example or a screen shot? I'm having trouble visualizing what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking those inline positioning styles off and see if that fixes anything:

```
<div>
   <div>
     <div id="MyModalWindow"> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also, you could probably just make the #MyModalWindow div sit outside of the page structure and add it to the end of your body by itself.  Then the jquery tools plugin should do the rest, like this:

```
<div>
   <div>         
   </div>
</div>
<div id="MyModalWindow"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS to select **MyModalWindow** would be:

```
  #MyModalWindow
    {
        position:relative;
        top:10px;
        left:10px;
    }
```

Where the # relates to `ids` and . relates to `classes`. The top and left properties will help you to position the div where you want it inside its parent.

And this HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute;">
     <div id="MyModalWindow"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery already attaches position:absolute; on the style of the div.

Comment: Ah, well use the properties: `top:10px;` and `left:10px;` these will help position your div inside its parent, change the px values to what works :)

Comment: Its a modal window to be in the center of the screen. Jquery calculates the position based on window size, etc. The parent is a tiny box.

Comment: You'll have to select somewhere else to make it in the markup, as if it's the child of a tiny div, it won't be able to display outside that div, so either place it as a top level element (near the top of your markup) or make the parent div bigger.